Request for help in installing Jazzy on Ubuntu 20.04
Has anyone successfully installed Jazzy on ROS2 or Ubuntu 20.04? I'm looking for guidance on how to install the Jazzy ROS distribution on Ubuntu 20.04. I believe I may need to compile it from source, but I'm not sure how to go about this process. Any tips, tutorials, or experiences would be greatly appreciated, especially regarding the compilation from source. If you've done this before, what steps did you follow? Were there any particular challenges or dependencies I should be aware of?Jazzy is for the Ubuntu 24.04 but its for a project and I need to stick to Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks in advance for your help!

Could you use Docker instead? I've seen several companies run newer versions of ROS in docker on an older OS. This, of course, works, and at least for ROS1 it even worked when it needed to communicate with ROS nodes on the host, running different versions of ROS.

@ChristianFritz, Thanks for the inputs. I am trying to install with the docker now.

@yigitboracagiran Thanks for the suggestions!!

You can use docker...
You can follow this for installing the docker on Ubuntu 20.
Then you need to pull jazzy's image...
You can follow this for installing jazzy's image.
